# Cambiar el icono de un archivo de audio en java

Tags: java, audio, mp3

quiero cambiar el icono que tiene por defecto un archivo de audio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por una propia por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado mirando con la librería jaudiotagger pero no he dado con la solución

Agradeceria alguna idea para poder hacerlo desde java

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a ver introduciendo esto en una clase de tu codigo:

```
Image icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/programa/imagenes/ejemplo.png")).getImage();
setIconImage(icon);
```

Aunque creo que esto solo cambia el icono del JFrame

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero como dices esto pone una imagen en  el JFrame o en algún componente de swing. Yo lo que necesito es como poner la imagen en alguna etequeta del archivo de audio para que se pueda ver, Si que he conseguido poner la imagen en el archivo peto no que se vea cuando abro la catpeta donde esta el archivo